# Multiple conditions in where clause returning more than expected

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to return all Corrective Actions that are late. If they are not completed by `DueDate` or not completed by `ExtendToDate`.

```
SELECT
   mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.DueDate
  ,mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.ExtendedToDate
  ,mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.Status
FROM
  mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions
WHERE 
  (DueDate < GETDATE() AND Status != 'Completed')
  or
  (ExtendedToDate < GETDATE() AND Status != 'Completed')
```

Heres what this query returns

```
DueDate          | ExtendToDate
2019-12-19       | 2020-01-17
2019-12-24       |
```

How do I write it so IF there is an `ExtendToDate` that is greater than today's date, it doesn't return that Corrective Action (2020-01-17)?

Comment: Don't you think since DueDate is fulfil that criteria, This record should come up in the approach. Do you only want those records who follows both the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ExtendedToDate` is `NULL`, and not an empty string as shown in the sample data, then using `COALESCE` should accomplish what you're after. This will compare the current date to the `ExtendedToDate` if it exists, or to the `DueDate` if `ExtendedToDate` is `NULL`, or to yesterday's date, if both `DueDate` and `ExtendedToDate` are `NULL`.

```
SELECT
   mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.DueDate
  ,mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.ExtendedToDate
  ,mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions.Status
FROM
  mfg.vw_Corrective_Actions
WHERE 
  Status != 'Completed'
  AND
  COALESCE(ExtendedToDate,DueDate,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())) < GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement in your sql.
Case when ExtendToDate <= get date() then  status end as status

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping I understood you, but if ExtendToDate is always defined, and if it's always greater or equal to the due date, then you don't even need to reference the due date.

If it isn't, then you'll need to add a clause for being defined or not being defined to your output.

So if it's defined, use it. If it's not defined, use the due date.

Comment: ExtendToDate will not always be defined :)

Comment: This is what I am working on trying to get Syntax right 
WHERE
Case when ExtendToDate <= GETDATE()
Else DueDate < GETDATE() AND Status != 'Completed'
end